# Undefined is not an object (evaluating ExponentConstants.linkinguri)

Tags: react-native, expo

Can someone guide me on this issue which shows up once I try using expo in my react native project.

Dependencies:

```
"expo": "^21.0.2",
"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.48.4",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.2.4",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13"
```

Error Message
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Having the same problem. I share the following packages:

"expo": "^21.0.2",
"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.48.4",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13". I hope this helps somewhat narrow the problem down.

Comment: Are you using the Expo client or did you just try to install the “expo” npm package? It looks like you might be trying to use the “expo” npm package with bare React Native.

Comment: Hi, I just installed the expo npm package. Can you please give me some clarity on how to use the expo client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use create-react-native-app to initiate my project, I don't see the issue that you mentioned. But if I use react-native init to create my project, I see the same issue. To fully take advantage of the integration of react native and expo client, do the following:

npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app YourProjectName

cd YourProjectName

npm start

Hope that helps.